# Can a landlord request reimbursement from a previous tenant on repairs made months after the lease has ended?

Tags: landlord, texas, tenant, residential-lease, pets

My previous landlord has recently contacted me about reimbursing him for repair fee 4 months after the lease has ended. The repairs involve damage caused by my pets, however we were already deducted our entire security deposit for repairs that included this pet damage.

He contacted me stating that additional repairs were required and that I should pay him back for the repairs. I responded that I have already paid for this through 2 non-refundable pet fees I paid at the beginning of our lease, as well as an addition pet fee on our monthly rent for a span of 2 years. These non-refundable pet fees and monthly pet fees were not part of our security deposit.

Am I still on the hook for these new repairs that he has found?

Thanks in advance.;